# knockout.js partial mapping from json

Tags: json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

On the knockout.js site's documentation they say that when you get data back from the server you can do this:

```
// Every time data is received from the server:
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel);
```

I'd like to partially map the data back into my object model.  Is that possible?

I have a viewModel.jobs[i].JobType child object, so I'd like to do something like this:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data.jobType, viewModel.jobs[i].JobType);
```

... meaning I'd like to just map in the jobType from the result from the server into this specific job's JobType field.

... Also keeping in mind:

```
// does not work because viewModel.jobs[i].JobType() is not a function.
viewModel.jobs[i].JobType(data.JobType);
```

Comment: wouldn't you want `viewmodel.jobs()[i]`, since `jobs` is probably observable?

Comment: I am only getting back the JobType property's values from the server's response.  I suppose it makes more sense to return the entire job?

Comment: Also, I'm not using viewModel.jobs()[i], I just have a direct reference to the job already.

Comment: I was talking about the last line of code in your question

Comment: Or, is there a way to replace a job in the array with the version from the server using mapping?

Comment: Tyrsius - your responses helped me get to my answer, which I'm posting now, so +1... and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

ko.mapping.fromJS(data.job, viewModel.jobs[i]);